# fancybox2 media helper not loading in window, launching vimeo site

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

i don't understand why the fancybox2 media helper isn't loading my vimeo content into a fancyboc, instead it is launching my video on the vimeo site.

any help is greatly appreciated.

will

from my fancybox.js file
`$('.fancybox-media-evcc')
                $(".fancybox").fancybox({
                    helpers : {
                    media : {}
                    }
                });`

from my html file
`<p><a class="fancybox-media-evcc" href="http://vimeo.com/58950757">
            <img src="images/thumbs/video.jpg" alt="Video prepared for the NYC Landmarks Commission"></a>
        </p>`

Answer (score 0):

This :

```
$('.fancybox-media-evcc') $(".fancybox").fancybox({ helpers : { media : {} } });
```

... **is incorrect**, it should rather be :

```
$('.fancybox-media-evcc').fancybox({ 
    helpers : { 
      media : {} 
    } 
});
```

Or you could have both :

```
// for elements with class fancybox
$(".fancybox").fancybox(); 

// for elements with class fancybox-media-evcc
$('.fancybox-media-evcc').fancybox({ 
    helpers : { 
      media : {} 
    } 
});
```